# Pandas version of "If True, VLOOKUP here, If False, VLOOKUP somewhere else

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transition a large data set and its processing from Excel to Python/Pandas, and I'm running into a snag when trying to implement a pandas version of "IF(col A = x, VLOOKUP(col B in table Y), otherwise, VLOOKUP(col A in table Z))".

I have created two separate dictionaries that will serve as the pandas versions of tables Y and Z, but I haven't been able to find the construct that can tell pandas to use the value from column B to look in the dictionary.

In trying this with pandas:

```
# Created a function to map the values from
#  PROD_TYPE to the prod_dict.
def map_values(row, prod_dict):
    return prod_dict[row]

# Created the dictionaries / old VLOOKUP tables.
prod_dict = {'PK': 'Packaging',
               'ML': 'Mix',
               'CM': 'Textile',
               'NK': 'Metallic'}

pack_dict = {'PK3' : 'Misc Packaging',
             'PK4' : 'Mix Packaging',
             'PK9' : 'Textile Packaging'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'PROD_TYPE' : ['PK', 'ML', 'ML', 'CM'], 
                   'PKG_TYPE': ['PK3', 'PK4', 'PK4', 'PK9'],
                   'VALUE': [1000, 900, 800, 700]})
# Apply the map_values function.
df['ITEM'] = df['PROD_TYPE'].apply(map_values, args = (prod_dict,))
```

I get:

```
  PROD_TYPE PKG_TYPE  VALUE       ITEM
0        PK      PK3   1000  Packaging
1        ML      PK4    900        Mix
2        ML      PK4    800        Mix
3        CM      PK9    700    Textile
```

When what I'm looking for is:

```
  PROD_TYPE PKG_TYPE  VALUE            ITEM
0        PK      PK3   1000  Misc Packaging
1        ML      PK4    900             Mix
2        ML      PK4    800             Mix
3        CM      PK9    700         Textile
```

Or, put more plainly: If `PROD_TYPE` is `'PK'`, look up the value from the column `PKG_TYPE` in the `pack_dict`; otherwise, look up `PROD_TYPE` in the `prod_dict`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted? It requires values from two columns in a hierarchy so it's not so simple to pull off.

Comment: So, `pack_dict` takes precedent, always?

Comment: Well in `pandas` or in `sql` a Vlookup is just a join. could you just write an if statement that in psuedo code reads `if value = 'foo' then join *certain way* elif value = 'bar' then join *other way*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would tackle this problem:

```
# First we make two dataframes out of the dictionaries with pd.melt
df2 = pd.DataFrame(prod_dict, index=[0])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(pack_dict, index=[0])

df2 = df2.melt(var_name=['PROD_TYPE'], value_name = 'ITEM')
df3 = df3.melt(var_name=['PKG_TYPE'], value_name = 'ITEM')

# df2
    PROD_TYPE   ITEM
0   PK          Packaging
1   ML          Mix
2   CM          Textile
3   NK          Metallic

# df3
    PKG_TYPE    ITEM
0   PK3         Misc Packaging
1   PK4         Mix Packaging
2   PK9         Textile Packaging

# Now we can merge our information together on keycolumns PROD_TYPE and PKG_TYPE
df_final = pd.merge(df, df2, on='PROD_TYPE')
df_final = pd.merge(df_final, df3, on='PKG_TYPE')

    PROD_TYPE   PKG_TYPE    VALUE   ITEM_x      ITEM_y
0   PK          PK3         1000    Packaging   Misc Packaging
1   ML          PK4         900     Mix         Mix Packaging
2   ML          PK4         800     Mix         Mix Packaging
3   CM          PK9         700     Textile     Textile Packaging

# Finally we use np.where to conditionally select the values we need 
df_final['ITEM'] = np.where(df_final.PROD_TYPE == 'PK', df_final.ITEM_y, df_final.ITEM_x)

# Drop columns which are not needed in output
df_final.drop(['ITEM_x', 'ITEM_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    PROD_TYPE   PKG_TYPE    VALUE   ITEM
0   PK          PK3         1000    Misc Packaging
1   ML          PK4         900     Mix
2   ML          PK4         800     Mix
3   CM          PK9         700     Textile
```

`np.where` is from the `numpy` module and works as follows:
`np.where(condition, true value, false value)`

Comment: Nice work. I suspect this is actually quite slow (2 melts, 2 merges...)  but I'm at a loss for a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks, you mean slow in terms of steps? Cause I dont think, `melt`, `merge` or `np.where` are slow. But I agree with you, this could be faster if we had something like this in pandas `pd.merge(....).query( value1 if x.ITEM=.., ese y.ITEM)`

Comment: `np.where` doesn't concern me much, but I _suspect_ there is quite a bit of overhead in the merge. Like I said, though, nice approach. I'd be curious to see other answers.

Comment: I agree with you there. Also quite curious of other answers and if its possible much shorter than my approach.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Aaaand gives me some more things to look up for understanding this weekend.  Thanks @Erfan!

Comment: Youre welcome @PAWeston, if you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: @Erfan: much shorter using `pd.Series.map()`, but you're right that `np.where` is the key to speed here as it processes both conditions in one call.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to answer from @Erfan, using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but skipping the `melt` to use [`pd.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).
With the variables from the question:

```
In []: df['ITEM'] = pd.np.where(df.PROD_TYPE == "PK",
                                df.PKG_TYPE.map(pack_dict),
                                df.PROD_TYPE.map(prod_dict))

In []: df
Out[]:
  PROD_TYPE PKG_TYPE  VALUE            ITEM
0        PK      PK3   1000  Misc Packaging
1        ML      PK4    900             Mix
2        ML      PK4    800             Mix
3        CM      PK9    700         Textile
```

Note that `numpy` is already loaded by `pandas`, just use `pd.np`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
df["ITEM"]= [pack_dict[row[1]["PKG_TYPE"]] 
    if row[1]["PROD_TYPE"] == "PK"     
    else     prod_dict[row[1]["PROD_TYPE"]] 
    for row in df.iterrows()]
```

I found this to be about 10 times faster than Erfan's solution.

Comment: This is a `for` loop in a list comprehension, performance will not scale on a large dataframe. Try it on `dflarge = pd.concat([df] * 100)`, imagine on `dflarge = pd.concat([df] * 100000)`.

Comment: @FabienP I measured the following times: Original: 2 ms, x100 39 ms, x1000 476 ms, x100000: 44 sec. Looks to me that it's scaling roughly linearly. Do you think the other answer scales sublinearly?

Comment: `numpy` (and *de facto* `pandas`) rely on C-libraries to parallelize these operations, it will not scale linearily with this kind of computation. With my solution I find 1.14ms for original, 1.2ms for *100, 1.75ms for *1,000 and 64.7ms for *100,000. Ends up with 652ms for *1,000,000 where you begin to see linearity. At this scale, probably `spark` would shine.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using boolean indexing

```
is_pk = df.PROD_TYPE == "PK"
df.loc[is_pk, "ITEM"] = df.loc[is_pk, "PROD_TYPE"].map(pack_dict)
df.ITEM.fillna(df.PROD_TYPE.map(prod_dict), inplace = True)
```